# Using R to scrape data from a table populated possibly with javascript

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping

Hello fellow R fanatics...

I've been using R to scrape data from a variety of websites for a while now, however this one has me stumped.

I am trying to scrape the data from the following table:
http://www.vigimeteo.com/PREV/obs/obs_seul.html?a=07005&b=

However my efforts thus far have failed.

I have tried the following

1. Simple wget, which results in the html from the site, and some of the javascript functions used to populate the table, but I haven't been able to really look through it and find the parts that I could use to grab the data using some of R's JS utilities.  It might be that my experience with JS is quite poor
2. I tried the solution here [Reading data from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377443/scraping-table-within-iframe-using-r-rvest-library), b/c it looked like the original website had the table in an iframe, but again no luck
3. A combination of getURL and readHTMLTable

   `thisURL = http://www.vigimeteo.com/PREV/obs/obs_seul.html?a=07005&b=
     theURL = getURL(thisURL,.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )
     tables = readHTMLTable(theURL)`

This results in an empty table

4. Spent about an hour going through every part of the html and javascript code I could find, but with limited success as detailed in 1.

It appears maybe [R's Selenium package could have a potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327980/scraping-xml-javascript-table-with-r), but I haven't yet figured out how to use it here, probably due to unfamiliarity

I feel like I'm just missing an essential part here... perhaps due to my lack of knowledge of JS and XML?

**UPDATE**:

I've noticed that if I right-click on the table element and use Chrome's "inspect" it generates HTML that has all of the table's values in it and would be very scrape-able... I'm still not sure how to get to this point in R though.  Anyone have hints on where to look in the "inspect" screen to try and guide my progress?

Comment: Just copying and pasting into a spreadsheet seems effective.

Comment: copy paste isn't an option, this is part of a workflow that needs to be automated, and is preferably in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this was the following.

1. Using the source code, identify the source html for the table
2. Navigate to the source page, and use Chrome developer tools > Network > XHR
3. Refresh the page to find the source of the data
4. Scrape from that source

Thanks to @XR SC for his answer here: [web scraping using Chrome Dev Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389772/how-can-i-scrape-data-from-a-website-within-a-frame-using-r) for providing the basic approach.